# How to send data manually using twisted

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I'm new to twisted framework.

And I know there are many callback function will trigger automatically

When the connection made or lost.

But I have no idea how to send the data  without those callbacks.

For example , I want to put an method `custom_write()` for sending the data out.

```
    def custom_write(self,data):
        self.transport.write(
            data)
```

And trigger the function in my `main():` method.

```
def main():
    try:
        p_red("I'm Client")
        f = EchoFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost",
                            8000,
                            f)
```

by the  `reactor.custom_write("HAHAHA")`

And what if I create multiple reactor binding in different port.

`Eg: localhost:1234, localhsot:5678`

and send the different two messages to the 2 connections.

Eg: `"Thanks" to port 1234` , `Bye~ to port 5678`

Any information can give me.

Thanks

```
class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(
            "I'm cli")

    def custom_write(self,data):
        self.transport.write(
            data)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Server said:", data 
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        pass

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print("[{0}] Lose connection...".format(
            self.__class__.__name__)
        )
        pass        

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    protocol = EchoClient
    """docstring for EchoFactory"""
    def clientConnectionFailed(self,
                               connector,
                               reason):
        print "[{0}] Connection failed - goodbye".format(
            self.__class__.__name__)
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self,
                             connector,
                             reason):        
        print "[{0}] Connection lost - goodbye".format(
            self.__class__.__name__)    
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    try:
        p_red("I'm Client")
        f = EchoFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost",
                            8000,
                            f)
        try:
            reactor.run()
        except BaseException  as e:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise e

        pass
    except BaseException  as e:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        raise e

    pass
```

Comment: don't catch `BaseException`. You probably want to allow KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `connectTCP()` more than once and using different hosts, ports. `connectTCP()` returns immediately without waiting for the full exchange to complete. To send different strings, you could pass them into the factories that can make them available to protocols.

Comment: Hm but I can only call reactor.run() once..... And to update the new quote or string I want to send I make a new connection and then I need to run reactor.run() or??

Comment: @sqp_125: usually, you run `reactor.run()` exactly once. The rest happens in asynchronous manner. To make the code look like it is synchronious (it might be more familiar) You could run `task.react(main, sys.argv[1:])` instead. For example, see [Mail Client on the Twisted home page](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)
Note: `connectTCP` is relatively low level, see whether [simpler clients would work in your case](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html)