# Persistent connection in twisted

Tags: twisted

I'm new in Twisted and have one question. How can I organize a persistent connection in Twisted? I have a queue and every second checks it. If have some - send on client. I can't find something better than call dataReceived every second.
Here is the code of Protocol implementation:

```py
class SyncProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    # ... some code here
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if(self.orders_queue.has_new_orders()):
            for order in self.orders_queue:
                self.transport.write(str(order))

        reactor.callLater(1, self.dataReceived, data)  # 1 second delay
```

It works how I need, but I'm sure that it is very bad solution. How can I do that in different way (flexible and correct)? Thanks.

P.S. - the main idea and alghorithm:
1. Client connect to server and wait
2. Server checks for update and pushes data to client if anything changes
3. Client do some operations and then wait for other data

Comment: Apart from anything else, you really really really shouldn't call `dataReceived` like this.  The code would work just as well if you put this logic into a method that didn't *already* have some (different, incompatible) meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing how the snippet you provided links into your `internet.XXXServer` or `reactor.listenXXX` (or `XXXXEndpoint` calls), its hard to make head-or-tails of it, but...

First off, in normal use, a twisted `protocol.Protocol`'s `dataReceived` would only be called by the framework itself.  It would be linked to a client or server connection directly or via a factory and it would be automatically called as data comes into the given connection. (The vast majority of twisted protocols and interfaces (if not all) are interrupt based, not polling/callLater, thats part of what makes Twisted so CPU efficient)

So if your shown code is actually linked into Twisted via a `Server` or `listen` or `Endpoint` to your clients then I think you will find very bad things will happen if your clients ever send data (... because twisted will call `dataReceived` for that, which (among other problems) would add extra `reactor.callLater` callbacks and all sorts of chaos would ensue...)

If instead, the code isn't linked into twisted connection framework, then your attempting to reuse twisted classes in a space they aren't designed for (... I guess this seems unlikely because I don't know how non-connection code would learn of a transport, unless your manually setting it...)

The way I've been build building models like this is to make a completely separate class for the polling based I/O, but after I instantiate it, I push my client-list (server)factory into the polling instance (something like `mypollingthing.servfact = myserverfactory`) there-by making a way for my polling logic to be able to call into the clients .write (or more likely a def I built to abstract to the correct level for my polling logic)

I tend to take the examples in Krondo's [Twisted Introduction](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) as one of the canonical examples of how to do twisted (other then twisted matrix), and the example in [part 6](http://krondo.com/?p=1595), under "Client 3.0" `PoetryClientFactory` has a `__init__` that sets a callback in the factory.

If I try blend that with the [twistedmatrix chat example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/examples/chatserver.py) and a few other things, I get:
(You'll want to change `sendToAll` to whatever your `self.orders_queue.has_new_orders()` is about)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ServerFactory

class PollingIOThingy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sendingcallback = None # Note I'm pushing sendToAll into here in main
        self.iotries = 0

    def pollingtry(self):
        self.iotries += 1
        print "Polling runs: " + str(self.iotries)
        if self.sendingcallback:
            self.sendingcallback("Polling runs: " + str(self.iotries) + "\n")

class MyClientConnections(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Got new client!"
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Lost a client!"
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

class MyServerFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = MyClientConnections

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []

    def sendToAll(self, message):
      for c in self.clients:
        c.transport.write(message)

def main():
    client_connection_factory = MyServerFactory()

    polling_stuff = PollingIOThingy()

    # the following line is what this example is all about:
    polling_stuff.sendingcallback = client_connection_factory.sendToAll
    # push the client connections send def into my polling class

    # if you want to run something ever second (instead of 1 second after
    # the end of your last code run, which could vary) do:
    l = task.LoopingCall(polling_stuff.pollingtry)
    l.start(1.0) 
    # from: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/time.html

    reactor.listenTCP(5000, client_connection_factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

To be fair, it might be better to inform `PollingIOThingy` of the callback by passing it as an arg to it's `__init__` (that is what is shown in Krondo's docs), For some reason, I tend to miss connections like this when I read code and find class-cheating easier to see, but that may just by my personal brain-damage.

Comment: Mike, thank you so much! Its really what I want and what I can't understand. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to help!  BTW, If its a match to your question, mark my post as the answer.

Comment: Hey Mike, thaks for that great answer. I still wonder however how I can send manually messages from a client to a server (e.g. by pressing a button in a GUI etc.). In my understanding to do this I have to call reactor.run() multiple times... (which is not allowed!)  Glad if you could provide an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396649/how-to-send-data-manually-using-twisted)

Comment: Hi @sqp_125! If keyboard input is what your after (unsure which way you mean "button in a GUI") I have examples in some of my other SO replies, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397425/how-to-deal-with-multiple-serial-ports-for-r-w-using-twisted/30399317#30399317

Comment: Hey Mike, no I want to connect twisted with my pyqt5 gui app. However I did not find any example of how to do that. And in my gui I want to have a send button and use twisted for sending a message (manually). It seems that for doing this I need to execute reactor.run() multiple times. But this is not allowed.   I have no idea how to pass e.g. ServerFactory and e.g. QObject into a class....

Comment: @sqp_125 I don't have direct experience with pyqt5, but googling it looks like it may have its own event loop - if that's true, how are you integrating that with twisted?  are you using something like https://github.com/sunu/qt5reactor ? - as you point out, you CAN'T have multiple reactor.run() - so the solution is integrating everything into ONE event loop (AKA reactor)

Comment: All right... I have to figure out what I do.... thanks for sharing the link.