# What is the correct way to access a protocols transport in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

In the TCP client example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


# a client protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    """Once connected, send a message, then print the result."""

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("hello, world!")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Server said:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection lost"

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()


# this connects the protocol to a server runing on port 8000
def main():
    f = EchoFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, f)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a periodic task that needs to send data to the server. All the logic for the task is outside the Protocol and Factory. Is it bad form to pass around `f` and use `f.protocol.transport.write("Something?")`?

Answer (score 2):

You can restructure your code and take advantage of some new-ish APIs to avoid having to do extra work in the factory to accomplish your goals.  Mike Lutz's answer is perfectly correct and what I used to suggest to people before endpoints.  Now that we have endpoints, I suggest that people use those instead.

The endpoint APIs let you write a main function that looks more like this:

```
def main():
    e = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 8000)
    f = EchoFactory()
    d = e.connect(f)
    d.addCallback(connected)
    return d

def connected(protocol):
    # protocol is an instance of EchoClient and is connected
    return LoopingCall(doStuff, protocol).start(3)
```

You might also consider adapting this to use `twisted.internet.task.react` which will take care of some of the reactor bookkeeping for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new-ish to the Twisted world too, so take me with a grain of salt, but I say its acceptable form.

See the following SO were I gave an example of how to hook parts of twisted together: [Persistent connections in twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265609/persistent-connection-in-twisted/23274411#23274411). (as it happens that answer talks about periodic tasks too...)

**EDIT**

Ooops, wait.  You have a factory in there.

The factory is making a new instance of the the protocol each time there is a connection, so your `f.protocol.transport.write` won't work (the `protocol` will point to the class, not a connected instance of the class).  Try running my code sample from the [Persistent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265609/persistent-connection-in-twisted/23274411#23274411) question, I make a connection list (the `self.clients` in the factory), using that structure you can use the `.write` of the various connections by iterating through the connection list