# ReactorNotRestartable error

Tags: python-2.7, upnp, reactor, twisted.internet

I have a tool, where i am implementing upnp discovery of devices connected in network.

For that i have written a script and used datagram class in it.

Implementation:
whenever scan button is pressed on tool, it will run that upnp script and will list the devices in the box created in tool.

This was working fine.

But when i again press the scan button, it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool\ui\main.py", line 508, in updateDevices
    upnp_script.main("server", localHostAddress)
  File "tool\ui\upnp_script.py", line 90, in main
    reactor.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1191, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1171, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 683, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Main function of upnp script:

```
def main(mode, iface):
    klass = Server if mode == 'server' else Client
    obj = klass
    obj(iface)
    reactor.run()
```

There is server class which is sending M-search command(upnp) for discovering devices.

```
MS = 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: %s:%d\r\nMAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\nMX: 2\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

In server class constructor, after sending m-search i am stooping reactor

```
reactor.callLater(10, reactor.stop)
```

From google i found that, we cannot restart a reactor beacause it is its limitation.

```
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhycanttheTwistedsreactorberestarted
```

Please guide me how can i modify my code so that i am able to scan devices more than 1 time and don't get this "reactor not restartable error"

Answer (score 1):

In response to "Please guide me how can i modify my code...", you haven't provided enough code that I would know how to specifically guide you, I would need to understand the (twisted part) of the logic around your scan/search.

If I were to offer a generic design/pattern/mental-model for the "twisted reactor" though, I would say **think of it as your programs main loop**.  (thinking about the `reactor` that way is what makes the problem obvious to me anyway...)

I.E. most long running programs have a form something like

```
def main():
    while(True):
       check_and_update_some_stuff()
       sleep 10
```

That same code in twisted is more like:

```
def main():
    # the LoopingCall adds the given function to the reactor loop
    l = task.LoopingCall(check_and_update_some_stuff)
    l.start(10.0)
    reactor.run() # <--- this is the endless while loop
```

If you think of the reactor as "the endless loop that makes up the `main()` of my program" then you'll understand why no-one is bothering to add support for "restarting" the reactor.  Why would you want to restart an endless loop? Instead of stopping the core of your program, you should instead only surgically stop the task inside that is complete, leaving the main loop untouched.

You seem to be implying that the current code will keep "sending m-search"s endlessly when the reactor is running.  So change your sending code so it stops repeating the "send"  (... I can't tell you how to do this because you didn't provide code, but for instance, a `LoopingCall` can be turned off by calling its `.stop` method.

Runnable example as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ServerFactory

class PollingIOThingy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sendingcallback = None # Note I'm pushing sendToAll into here in main()
        self.l = None # Also being pushed in from main()
        self.iotries = 0

    def pollingtry(self):
        self.iotries += 1
        if self.iotries > 5:
            print "stoping this task"
            self.l.stop()
            return()
        print "Polling runs: " + str(self.iotries)
        if self.sendingcallback:
            self.sendingcallback("Polling runs: " + str(self.iotries) + "\n")

class MyClientConnections(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Got new client!"
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Lost a client!"
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

class MyServerFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = MyClientConnections

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []

    def sendToAll(self, message):
      for c in self.clients:
        c.transport.write(message)


# Normally I would define a class of ServerFactory here but I'm going to
# hack it into main() as they do in the twisted chat, to make things shorter

def main():
    client_connection_factory = MyServerFactory()

    polling_stuff = PollingIOThingy()

    # the following line is what this example is all about:
    polling_stuff.sendingcallback = client_connection_factory.sendToAll
    # push the client connections send def into my polling class

    # if you want to run something ever second (instead of 1 second after
    # the end of your last code run, which could vary) do:
    l = task.LoopingCall(polling_stuff.pollingtry)
    polling_stuff.l = l
    l.start(1.0)
    # from: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/time.html

    reactor.listenTCP(5000, client_connection_factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This script has extra cruft in it that you might not care about, so just focus on the `self.l.stop()` in `PollingIOThingy`s `polling try` method and the `l` related stuff in `main()` to illustrates the point.

(this code comes from SO: [Persistent connection in twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23265609/3334178) check that question if you want to know what the extra bits are about)